# How to show the nearest city to the given by location?

Tags: android, kotlin

Nearest city will do just fine. But I cant do it. I AM developing in kotlin by the way. But if you give java code, I might try to change to kotlin, it doesn't always succeed though.
So, I searched all topics related to this but they didn't work. Maybe cuz they were in java, I don't know. Code works, except it doesn't show the nearest city.

So, I added this code into my mainactivity.kt, inside one of the onclick:

```
                val gcd = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
                var addresses: List<Address>? = null
                if (addresses != null && addresses.size > 0) {
                    val locality = addresses[0].locality
                }
```

I've tried something but it doesn't work. Here is my mainactivity.kt:

```
package com.example.camlockotlin
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Address
import android.location.Geocoder
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import java.util.*
import android.view.View;
import java.io.IOException


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val requestpermissionbutonu = findViewById<Button>(R.id.requestpermissionbutonu)
        requestpermissionbutonu.setOnClickListener {
            requestPermissions()


        }
        val lokasyoniste = findViewById<Button>(R.id.lokasyoniste)
        lokasyoniste.setOnClickListener {
            lokasyonizniseysi()
            val gcd = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
            var addresses: List<Address>? = null

            if (addresses != null && addresses.size > 0) {
                val locality = addresses[0].locality
            }
        }

    }
    private fun kameraiznivar() =
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    private fun lokasyononiznivar() =
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    private fun lokasyonarkaplaniznivar() =
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    private fun requestPermissions() {
        var permissionsToRequest=mutableListOf<String> ()
        if(!kameraiznivar()) {
            permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        }

        if(permissionsToRequest.isNotEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray(), 0)

        }
    }

    private fun lokasyonizniseysi() {
        var permissionsToRequest=mutableListOf<String> ()
        if(!lokasyononiznivar()) {
            permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        }
        if(!lokasyonarkaplaniznivar()) {
            permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
        }
        if(permissionsToRequest.isNotEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray(), 0)

        }
    }
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode==0 && grantResults.isNotEmpty()){
            for(i in grantResults.indices){
                if(grantResults[i]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Log.d("PermissionsRequest", "${permissions[i]} granted.")
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code is ok.

Permissions are like:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I want it to  print it like, "You are here in California" like this. In the most basic text way.

Comment: var addresses: List<Address>? = null
                if (addresses != null && addresses.size > 0) {
                    val locality = addresses[0].locality
                } how do you really expect to run this if statement where you have not set the addresses list?

Comment: I did it already now. Will add details.